# Ternary operator spoil OR-conditional

Tags: java, ternary

Execution of statement

```
true || true ? false : true
```

returns `false`.

Shouldn't it be true since OR conditional will not execute ternary operation (right hand side part)?

Comment: Maybe you will understood more if you put parenthesis like this : `boolean b = (true || true) ? false : true;`

Comment: Why should it not execute the ternary operation? This looks to be equivalent to `(true || true) ? false : true`

Comment: Should have been easily found out in the official documentation on [Operator Precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
true || true ? false : true
```

is the same as

```
(true || true) ? false : true
```

If you meant:

```
true || (true ? false : true)
```

then you have to add the brackets yourself.

Answer (score 3):

`true || true ? false : true` is like writing:

```
if(true || true) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Since `true` is... *true*, then the whole expression is *true*, so you return `false`.